# route 53 domain not working without http in aws

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have my domain, `ixxxxxx.com`, i have configured that domain with aws, when i run my domain as `http://ixxxxx.com` it works fine, but without http it is not working, can anyone please help me what changes i need to do in aws to resolve this issue ? any help will be really appreciated, i know its something small issue but didn't identified it, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue ? it also works with `www.ixxxx.com`, don't know what exact issue in that.

Comment: is this url blocked by TRAI ?

Comment: how many `x`'s are there in your domain name?

Comment: it is not x for privacy i didn't specify the domain name

Comment: It is very difficult to troubleshoot DNS issues without knowing the real domain name...